# Is Chiliz a sidechain? How to get transactions from it?

Tags: nodes

Suppose I want information about some ERC20 token. I run Ethereum mainnet node of my preference, load all events of ERC20 token of my interest with eth_getLogs, and do whatever I want with that info.

Now what if I'm interested in transfers of a fan token Chiliz implements? As I understand, Chiliz has a sidechain viewable here: https://explorer.chiliz.com/ But how do I run a node which serves this blockchain?

Answer (score 0):

OK, got an answer on Chiliz's discord. Their blockchain is private, they are planning on letting outsiders connect to it, but currently this is not possible.